# JAXB - getting input Element after unmarshalling

Tags: java, dom, jaxb

I would like to work with unmarshalled document for comfort reasons, but I also need to have access to the original source XML `Element`s (to access empty text nodes, because some cryptography is involved). Is there a way to achieve this with JAXB2 (preferably using a maven plugin) or do I need to unmarshall the contents manually?

Answer (score 0):

JAXB isn't going to differentiate between empty and missing nodes, the unmarshalled object is going to have nulls in either case, so if there is a semantic difference between the two, think you'll have to manually parse or use a different parser that can give you the insight you need (not sure, SAX parser might).